# how to extract data from restclient.entity.UserEntities in openfire rest API?

Tags: java, rest, openfire

I am using this : [Openfire Rest API](https://github.com/igniterealtime/REST-API-Client)

Now I am fetching users and groups using a java file.
In response I was expecting XML data, but it shows me strange data.

**I am new to Java** so I don't know how to extract data from this.

My Code is :

```
package bizrtc;

import api.restclient.RestClient;
import api.restclient.RestApiClient;
import api.restclient.entity.AuthenticationToken;
import api.restclient.entity.UserEntities;
import api.restclient.entity.GroupEntities;


import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;


/**
 *
 * @author Rajan
 */
public class Bizrtc 
{
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
       // TODO code application logic here
       AuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new AuthenticationToken("cn1ed9s8yEf5woQV");
       // Set Openfire settings (9090 is the port of Openfire Admin Console)
       RestApiClient restApiClient = new RestApiClient("192.168.50.50", 9090, authenticationToken);
      // restApiClient.getUsers();
       UserEntities users = restApiClient.getUsers();

       System.out.println("The Groups are as below: "+restApiClient.getGroups());

       System.out.println("Now fetching data from openfire Server");
       System.out.println("The data is *******************************" + users.toString());

    }



}
```

And when I run the program I get:

```
Dec 23, 2016 3:58:43 PM org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter log
INFO: 1 * Sending client request on thread main
1 > GET http://192.168.50.50:9090/plugins/restapi/v1/groups
1 > Authorization: cn1ed9s8yEf5woQV
1 > Content-Type: application/xml

Dec 23, 2016 3:58:44 PM org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter log
INFO: 1 * Client response received on thread main
1 < 200
1 < Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
1 < Access-Control-Allow-Headers: origin, content-type, accept, authorization
1 < Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD
1 < Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
1 < Content-Length: 3664
1 < Content-Type: application/xml
1 < Date: Fri, 23 Dec 2016 09:53:38 GMT
1 < Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
1 < Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=1bt213yrejbmfkpyfs53snplm;Path=/;HttpOnly
1 < X-Frame-Options: deny

The Groups are as below: api.restclient.entity.GroupEntities@1165b38
Now fetching data from openfire Server
The data is *******************************api.restclient.entity.UserEntities@4c12331b
```

How To print this users in XML or better to ARRAY format ??

How do i get the users from this response:api.restclient.entity.GroupEntities@1165b38

Do i have to convert this to string or something like that ?

Comment: What jar file have you used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `UserEntities` Java code:

```
@XmlRootElement(
    name = "users"
)
public class UserEntities {
    List<UserEntity> users;

    public UserEntities() {
    }

    public UserEntities(List<UserEntity> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

    @XmlElement(
        name = "user"
    )
    public List<UserEntity> getUsers() {
        return this.users;
    }

    public void setUsers(List<UserEntity> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }
}
```

It's a single POJO class with a list of users and mapped with [JAXB](https://jaxb.java.net/) annotations. This means you can easily convert your object to XML, JSON or whatever the lib enables.

**XML way:**

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(UserEntities.class);
Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
jaxbMarshaller.marshal(users, sw);
String xmlString = sw.toString();

System.out.println(xmlString);
```

And if you want an array of `UserEntity`'s, you already have its `List`:

```
final UserEntity[] arrayUsers = (UserEntity[]) users.getUsers().toArray();
```

Return example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<users>
    <user>
        <username>d</username>
        <name>e</name>
        <email>a@a.com</email>
        <password>pass</password>
    </user>
</users>
```